# Single Word Request - Supremacy Based off of Arrogance

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word (or small phrase) to express the idea of someone being racist/sexist/generally supremacist for a specific reason; namely a version of the supremacy from a "logic" along the lines of "I am great, therefore people like me are good, and people NOT like me are bad".

I am looking to describe a fairly flexible sort of thing where instead of thinking "My people are superior", they think "I am superior and that person is like me".
I would not say xenophobic as that seems more focused on disliking outsiders, instead of naively overvaluing themself.
In a sentence one might say, "He's not racist per se but more accurately ______".

Does such a word or phrase exist?

**Edit: spelling**
Update after a few answers: Chauvinist and Supremacist alone carry the outward attitude I am trying to find but a key aspect of what I am looking for is a level of *personal narcissism* as the (possibly sole) driving factor.

Comment: Note:  The phrase is *"per se"* from Latin

Comment: Something like **elitist?**

Comment: Maybe a ***bigot***?

Comment: Narcissism? The notion (and word) you're looking for may well be a common one, but it also may be a concept too nuanced to match a single word. You may want to add what it is that it is not. "He's not racist per se but more accurately X" somehow implies that he is totally racist, but not primarily so, that the racism is a consequence of this other X property. Like the joke about the bigot who says he's not because he hates everybody equally.

Comment: @Mitch I sort of see your point about being too nuanced, but I have a memory of the perfect word being used, with a word I can't remember. I guess I could say something like group spread narcissism or narcissistic supremacy but I feel like there is, or should be, a more universally understood phrase.

Comment: can't believe no one mentioned Prejudiced

Answer (score 2):

[Elitism.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elitism)

> Elitism is the belief or attitude that individuals who form an elite—a
> select group of people with an intrinsic quality, high intellect,
> wealth, special skills, or experience—are more likely to be
> constructive to society as a whole, and therefore deserve influence or
> authority greater than that of others.

<sup>wikipedia.org</sup>

> practice of or belief in rule by an elite.
>
> consciousness of or pride in belonging to a select or favored group.

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/elitism)

Answer (score 2):

I see nothing wrong with **supremacist** From Lexico:

> **[supremacist](https://www.lexico.com/definition/supremacist)**: A person who believes that a particular group, especially one determined by race, religion, or sex, is superior and should therefore dominate society.

If you drop "especially one determined by race, religion, or sex" -- which is not essential to the definition -- you have "a person who believes that a particular group is superior and should therefore dominate society." This is exactly the sort of person you've described in your question. If you want to talk about a particular type of **supremacist**, i.e., member of a group that believes itself superior or supreme, you need an adjective, e.g., *white* **supremacist**, *black* **supremacist**, *female* **supremacist**, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**chauvinistic**

> chauvinistic
>
> 2: undue partiality or attachment to a group or place to which one
> belongs or has belonged
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chauvinism

**narrow-minded**

> narrow-minded
> not willing to accept ideas or ways of behaving that
> are different from your own:
>
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/narrow-minded